# Trying to upgrade my vmware lab from 4.1 esxi to 5.5 esxi

Tags: esxi

Trying to upgrade my vmware lab.  I have a dell T410 server and recently purchased a 2 Terabyte SATA drive and 32 Gig of RAM.  Successfully installed both.  I also upgraded from vmware 4.1 ESKI to 5.5 ESXI.  I installed the 5.5 ESXI to a USB Cruz drive and it boots up fine and I see the data stores that were previously created.

The problem I’m having is that I cannot see the virtual machines that were created and I cannot see    the 2 Terabyte SATA Drive that was installed.  I pulled the drive out and formatted it using Windows 7 OS and created and then deleted a text file just to make sure that the drive was working.  So knowing that the drive is working I cannot figure out why 5.5 ESKI cannot see the drive or the virtual machines.

**Edit:**
I did not do any formatting.  I installed vmware 5.5 on a flash drive and booted from it, thinking that it would see the data stores and 2 TB drive.

I was hoping that it detect everything after booting up. I guess this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well...if you formatted it your data is gone from it. Additionally, did you go in to ESXi from the client and try to add the old datastore before all of this?
(see: https://www.itsupportguides.com/server-side-tips/vmware-esxi-5-how-to-add-a-new-storage-datastore/) My guess is that the upgrade didn't automatically load your datastore so you couldn't see the contents of it (ie. the VMs/isos).

If you can see your 2TB drive when trying to add in a new datastore now and, after you import it, you see no VMs (or you are asked to reformat it) you likely deleted the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

No did not do any formatting.  I installed vmware 5.5 on a flash drive and booted from it, thinking that it would see the data stores and 2 TB drive.

I was hoping that it detect everything after booting up. I guess this is not the case.

Comment: Hi likely Blake, goto [Help Center > Contact](http://superuser.com/contact) select "I need to merge user profiles" to be able to edit your question, please do not use the answer section for anything else than answers.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to respond to the suggested fix.